# eMac stuck - won't boot, won't eject disc

Tags: mac

I was upgrading from Jaguar 10.2.4 to Tiger 10.4.8 on my creaky old eMac.

Inserted the Install disk. When it restarted, I got the chime and Apple logo, then it aborted and a bunch of (to me) gibberish:  "no debugger configured ... Latest stack backtrace...  Proceeding back via exception chain... Kernel version... Panic: we are hanging here..."

Tried several times, but always stops and same message.

Don't have a Mac keyboard so no keyboard eject.  F12 does not eject disc. At this point I would be content to just stick with Panther but it's stuck in limbo.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to eject a disk during boot? (press left-mouse button continuously) Or how to boot from your install disk? (Press and hold C during boot) Or what could be the reason/solution for your error? (Faulty system, bad disk)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still like that but you could try to keep the mouse button pressed while booting: it used to force a disc eject.

Comment: Matteo's suggestion is valid. The optical drive could be failing or if you don't use it much, be contaminated with dust. After the disc ejects, try inserting/ejecting the disc a few more times in a row in an attempt to blow off some crud from the CD/DVD reader lens and 'unstick' the laser travel mechanism. To do this, you'll have to hard-boot a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manually eject the tray with a paper clip. Now back to square one (operating in Panther). Guess my question was why the install aborted or whether I need to do something differently to upgrade, like a system restore of Panther b/4 installing Tiger.